# How to work around IE6/IE7 margins disappearing when relatively-positioned floated div is moved with jquery .hover()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Here is my code:

[http://jsbin.com/uhera3/edit](http://jsbin.com/uhera3/)

When I use jQuery to .hover(), the relatively positioned floated divs jump to the left (seemingly losing their margins) in IE7.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest implementing [IE conditional tags](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and making an ie-fix.css file.